# GoogleApiClient: Games.API and Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API not working together

Tags: android, google-signin, google-api-client

I have a working application for signing in with a google account.

I'm building my client like this

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestProfile()
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
        .build();

GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
```

Now I decided to add the `Games.API` resulting in the following client:

```
GoogleApiClient  googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Games.API)
        .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .build();
```

However when I try to connect the client

```
googleApiClient.connect();
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use SIGN_IN_MODE_REQUIRED with GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API. Use connect(SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL) instead.
```

So I read the exception and modified my connection call to

```
googleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
```

So now I don't get any more exceptions but the client never gets connected for some reason. Any ideas why the client does not connect now?

**EDIT: Complete working code example**

```
package at.hakkon.space.signin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;

import at.hakkon.space.R;
import at.hakkon.space.activity.MainActivity;
import at.hakkon.space.application.ApplicationClass;



public class GoogleSignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "T1_GSignInActivity";

    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
    private boolean mSignInClicked = false;

    private static GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleSignInActivity");

        setupGoogleClient();
    }



    public void setupGoogleClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        ApplicationClass.getInstance().setGoogleClient(googleApiClient);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                googleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
                // Bring up an error dialog to alert the user that sign-in
                // failed. The R.string.signin_failure should reference an error
                // string in your strings.xml file that tells the user they
                // could not be signed in, such as "Unable to sign in."
                BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                        requestCode, resultCode, R.string.sign_in_other_error);
            }
        }
    }

    private void startNextActivity() {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Client Connection failed:\n" + connectionResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            // already resolving
            return;
        }

        // if the sign-in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
        // launch the sign-in flow
        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInflow) {
            mAutoStartSignInflow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

            // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
            // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
            // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
            // an issue with sign-in, please try again later."

            if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, googleApiClient, connectionResult, RC_SIGN_IN, R.string.sign_in_other_error)) {
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Conflict NOT RESOLVED :((", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Conflict RESOLVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                //startNextActivity();
            }

        }

        // Put code here to display the sign-in button

        //Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Client Connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        startNextActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Client Connection Suspended.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(callbacks)
            .build();
```

and then

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

if you configured your game in console correctly - it will connect and get access to games features (achievements and leaderboard for example)

```
class GoogleConnectionCallbacks implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        MyLogger.d("DBG_GGL_LDB", "connected");
        Player p = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient);
        String displayName;
        if (p == null) {
            Log.w("DBG_GGL_LDB", "mGamesClient.getCurrentPlayer() is NULL!");
            displayName = "???";
        } else {
            displayName = p.getDisplayName();
        }
        MyLogger.d("DBG_GGL_LDB", "Hello, " + displayName);

        if (mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API)) {

            MyLogger.d("DBG_GGL_LDB", "hasConnectedApi true - can user leaderboard");
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        MyLogger.d("DBG_GGL_LDB", "connection suspended");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        MyLogger.d("DBG_GGL_LDB", "connection failed " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());

    }
}
```

I've been facing this issue pretty long, It's all because of use `.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)`

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for your response but the code I posted actually works perfectly fine. I was so focused on my testing device that I didn't test any other devices. Turns out the other devices worked and after I reinstalled google play on the test evice it worked also.

Answer (score 0):

The code worked perfectly fine on any other device than my testing device. After reinstalling Google Play on my testing device it also worked! I don't know what caused the issues but the reinstall fixed it.

Turns out I ddin't need SIGN_IN at all. Look at Alexanders answer if you need it!

Comment: you have removed SIGN_IN api, that's why it started working I think, not because of reinstall

Comment: Huh you are right, its been 2 months now so details are fuzzy. Turns out I didn't need SignIn anymore. Still I had to reinstall google play for some reason to get it work.